# Error for import scrapy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, jupyter-notebook

I try to import scrapy in a Jupyter Notebook, but I get.

```
import scrapy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'.
```

However, in an RStudio Markdown, it works.

````
library(reticulate)

```{python}

import scrapy

```
````

or

````
```{r}

import("scrapy")

```
````

Any idea?

Module info:

```
C:\Users\X>pip show scrapy
Name: Scrapy
Version: 1.6.0
Summary: A high-level Web Crawling and Web Scraping framework
Home-page: https://scrapy.org
Author: Scrapy developers
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\X\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: six, cssselect, PyDispatcher, Twisted, w3lib, queuelib, lxml, service-identity, pyOpenSSL, parsel
Required-by:
```

Here is my version:

```
C:\Users\X>python --version
Python 3.7.0b5
```

Comment: did you install it ? `pip install scrapy`

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn´t work in the Markdown.

Comment: you may have two python installed - one used by RStudio - and it has installed scrapy - and second used in Jupiter - which doesn't have `scrapy`

Comment: Did you install python/jupyter using anaconda?

Comment: if you have two python then you have also two `pip` - and one of them may show `scrapy`. If you run `python jupiter` then use `python -m pip show scrapy` to check with the same python.

Comment: you can even use `python -m pip install scrapy` to install it with `python` which you use in `python -m jupyter notebook`

Comment: @razdi Yes, I did.

Comment: The location in the module info you showed above does not look like the one anaconda would use. I would suggest opening anaconda prompt and then trying to install scrapy.

Comment: @furas  I installed it that way i.e. python -m pip install scrapy. I did this after installing scrapy im R with py_install("scrapy")

Comment: @razdi This works, thanks.

Comment: do you run `jupyter` with `python -m jupyter notebook` ? Using other method may run jupyter with different python.